# UploadFileAsync in Java?

Tags: java, .net

How can I upload file to a server (API interface) in Java, just like the .NET programmers do in C#:

```
cli.UploadFileAsync(URL, filename);
```

Tried to do findout a way by using HttpClient but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [async http client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) is what you are looking for. Read through the docs and I am sure you can find your way.

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
Response response =
   client.preparePut(("http://sonatype.com/myFile.avi").execute();
```

Another blog explaining its usage: http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/going-asynchronous-using-asynchttpclient-the-basic/

Comment: man, thanks. been wondering how to do this for days. thanks a lot.